# Override Vuetify 2 SASS variables of grid, is working but the order of output classes is wrong

Tags: sass, vuetify.js

I just created a clean Vue CLI 4 project and added Vuetify by Vue CLI. On this step everything is working without problem.
By adding a `variables.scss` problem emerges:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  'xxs': 0,
  'xs': 375,
  'sm': 600px,
  'md': 960px,
  'lg': 1280px - 16px,
  'xl': 1920px - 16px,
  'xxl': 2560px - 16px
);
```

I wrote a simple 3 columns template:

```
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="12" md="4">1</v-col>
  <v-col cols="12" md="4">1</v-col>
  <v-col cols="12" md="4">1</v-col>
</v-row>
```

I expect to have 3 columns in `md` size but the specificity of the `.col-12` is higher than `.col-md-4` and col-md-4 never applies.

[image: CSS panel in DevTools]

Is this a bug? Or I'm doing something wrong?

*I tried to prepend variables.scss by adding it to vue.config.js, tried importing the variables.scss of node_modules/vuetify at the first/last line of my variables file.*

vuetify version: 2.2.17
sass version: 1.25.0
vuetify-loader version: 1.4.3

Github source code of the sample project: https://github.com/mort3za/temp-vuetify

Comment: Just found out that adding `xxs` to breakpoints makes this weird behavior.